# Adding filters to a nested collection

Tags: c#, wpf

In WPF I am creating a file explorer that display the files and folders of a specific path. I am building a node tree based on these classes :

```
class Node {
    public string Path {get;set;}
}
public class FolderNode {
    public ObservableCollection<NodeExplorateur> Childrens { get; set; }
    public ICollectionView ChildrensSorted { get; }
}
```

I am also using the FileSystemWatcher to update my tree based on the filesystem events. This tree is shared between several components that display the filesystem differently with a TreeView and a ListView with something like this :

```
<ExplorerTreeView x:Name="ExplorerLeft" RootNode="{Binding Controlleur.NodeRacine, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}" />
<ExplorerList RootNode="{Binding SelectedNode, ElementName=ExplorerLeft, Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

So that that there is interaction between the two components. Now I want to filter the nodes differently in both component, the TreeView should hide the files and display only folders while the ListView should have a search on the files.

And that's where I am stuck, handling filters on the ListView is simple enough with a ICollectionView but I don't know how I can make this in the TreeView (since the nodes are nested). I tried to create a CollectionView directly inside the HierarchicalDataTemplate XAML but without luck (tried a lot of different syntax) :

```
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemsSource>
                <CollectionViewSource Source="{Binding ChildrenSorted}" Filter="CollectionViewSource_Filter"/>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemsSource>
```

I also ended up by adding a ICollectionView to my FolderNode :

```
public class FolderNode {
    public ObservableCollection<NodeExplorateur> Childrens { get; set; }
    public ICollectionView ChildrensSorted { get; }
    public ICollectionView ChildrensFiltered { get; }
}
```

So that the TreeView can use the `ChildrensFiltered` to hide files, but that's seems a not very good solution since the more component I will get the more CollectionView I will have to add.

**What I would like to do instead (but don't know how) :**

How can I create a `CollectionViewSource` and pass it to a `TreeView.HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemsSource` in XAML ?

Or

How can I create a `CollectionViewSource` from a nested list (knowing that the list will be updated reguraly) ?

Comment: You already have a collectionview created for any collection you bind, there's a default one created.  Having said that. I would be inclined to filter anything using linq or whatever rather than collectionview. Collectionview is pretty slow.  If you use the same objects, your overhead on duplication is just the list or whatever contains the NodeExplorateur objects.

Comment: @Andy Good to know that CollectionView is slow. I am ok with duplicating the tree but since it's updated from the FileSystemWatcher that means I will have to update two list each time a file is moved / deleted / renamed, or reduplicate the tree each time (which seems pretty bad, if only to keep track of tje selected nodes).